# Replace exact numbers in a column keeping order

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have this file, and I would like to replace the number of the 3rd column so that they appear in order. Also, I would need to skip the first row (the header of the file).

Initial file:

```
#results from program A
    8536    17  1   CGTCGCCTAT  116 147M2D
    8536    17  1   CGTCGCTTAT  116 147M2D
    8536    17  1   CGTTGCCTAT  116 147M2D
    8536    17  1   CGTTGCTTAT  116 147M2D
    2005    17  3   CTTG    61  145M
    2005    17  3   TTCG    30  145M
    91823   17  4   ATGAAGC 22  146M
    91823   17  4   GTAGGCC 19  146M
    16523   17  5   GGGGGTCGGT  45  30M1D115M
```

Modified file:

```
#results from program A
    8536    17  1   CGTCGCCTAT  116 147M2D
    8536    17  1   CGTCGCTTAT  116 147M2D
    8536    17  1   CGTTGCCTAT  116 147M2D
    8536    17  1   CGTTGCTTAT  116 147M2D
    2005    17  2   CTTG    61  145M
    2005    17  2   TTCG    30  145M
    91823   17  3   ATGAAGC 22  146M
    91823   17  3   GTAGGCC 19  146M
    16523   17  4   GGGGGTCGGT  45  30M1D115M
```

Do you know how I could do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'prev!=$1{++count}{$3=count;prev=$1;$1=$1} 1' OFS="\t"  Input_file
```

To remove headers use following:

```
awk 'FNR==1{print;next}prev!=$1{++count}{$3=count;prev=$1;$1=$1} 1' OFS="\t"  Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** In case your Input_file's 1st field is NOT in order then following may help you here.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{if(!a[$1]++){b[$1]=++count};next} {$3=b[$1];$1=$1} 1' OFS="\t" Input_file  Input_file
```

To remove headers for 2nd solution above use following.

```
awk 'FNR==1{if(++val==1){print};next}FNR==NR{if(!a[$1]++){b[$1]=++count};next} {$3=b[$1];$1=$1} 1' OFS="\t" Input_file  Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

another minimalist `awk`

```
$ awk '{$3=c+=p!=$1;p=$1}1' file | column -t

8536   17  1  CGTCGCCTAT  116  147M2D
8536   17  1  CGTCGCTTAT  116  147M2D
8536   17  1  CGTTGCCTAT  116  147M2D
8536   17  1  CGTTGCTTAT  116  147M2D
2005   17  2  CTTG        61   145M
2005   17  2  TTCG        30   145M
91823  17  3  ATGAAGC     22   146M
91823  17  3  GTAGGCC     19   146M
16523  17  4  GGGGGTCGGT  45   30M1D115M
```

with header version

```
$ awk 'NR==1; NR>1{$3=c+=p!=$1;p=$1; print | "column -t"}' file

#results from program A
8536   17  1  CGTCGCCTAT  116  147M2D
8536   17  1  CGTCGCTTAT  116  147M2D
8536   17  1  CGTTGCCTAT  116  147M2D
8536   17  1  CGTTGCTTAT  116  147M2D
2005   17  2  CTTG        61   145M
2005   17  2  TTCG        30   145M
91823  17  3  ATGAAGC     22   146M
91823  17  3  GTAGGCC     19   146M
16523  17  4  GGGGGTCGGT  45   30M1D115M
```